# Updating Vlookup Formulas on Set time intervals using Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to understand how to use Script Editor to refresh Vlookup formulas on Google sheet at set time intervals.

Example of formula below:

```
={"Jira Ticket ID";ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D2:D,'Jira Ticket Details'!A:G,7,0))}
```

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: The result of `ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP([...]))` updates automatically when I change the data that feeds it. Could you give in what context are you using it?